# Pause function does not work in elif loop

Tags: python, selenium

I am running a code that joins google meets automatically and the very last few lines help to transition from one meeting to another. So, it checks the time, if it is some specific time, it joins a meeting, waits for some defined time, and then logs off. it is then supposed to join another call, and it does, but this time, it does it endlessly. so, I suppose the pause in the elif does not work, because the code just ignores it and opens meetings endlessly. how can I fix it? code is shown below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import datetime
import time
import signal
import pause

now = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M / %A")

justtime = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print (current_time)


def Glogin(mail_address, password):
    #os.system("obs --startvirtualcam &")
    # Login Page 
    driver.get( 
        'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/&ec=GAZAAQ') 

    # input Gmail 
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys(mail_address) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click() 
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 

    # input Password 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath( 
        '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(password) 
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click() 
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 

    # go to google home page 
    driver.get('https://google.com/') 
    driver.implicitly_wait(100)
    driver.get(sub)
    # turn off Microphone 
    time.sleep(1)
    #driver.find_elements_by_class_name("JRY2Pb")[0].click()
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("JRY2Pb")[0].click()
    # switch camera
    time.sleep(2)
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("JRtysb"):
        x.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    for a in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("FwR7Pc"):
        a.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    for b in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("XhPA0b"):
        b.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    # Join meet 
    time.sleep(1) 
    driver.implicitly_wait(2000) 
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector( 
        'div.uArJ5e.UQuaGc.Y5sE8d.uyXBBb.xKiqt').click()
    
# assign email id and password
mail_address = 'email'
password = 'password'

# create chrome instamce 
opt = Options() 
opt.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
opt.add_argument('--start-maximized')
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 0, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
})

while True:

    if current_time == "05:13 / Friday":
        sub = "https://meet.google.com/obu-evtm-kai"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver') 
        Glogin(mail_address, password)
        dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 29, 5, 14, 0, 0)
        pause.until(dt)
        driver.close()
    
    elif current_time == "05:14 / Friday":
        sub = "https://meet.google.com/obu-ev"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver') 
        Glogin(mail_address, password)
        dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 29, 5, 15, 0, 0)
        pause.until(dt)
        driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to get again the time inside the while loop so it won't loop forever.
Then i suggest you to use **time.sleep()** intead of pause.until beacuse you won't have to specify also the day.

```
while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        minutes = now.strftime("%M")
        seconds = now.strftime("%S")
        today = now.strftime("%A").strip()
        minutes = int(minutes)
        hour = int(hour)


        if hour==5 and today=='Friday':
                if minutes==12:
                        sub = "https://meet.google.com/obu-evtm-kai"
                        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver') 
                        Glogin(mail_address, password)
                        time.sleep(60)
                        driver.close()
                
                elif minutes == 14:
                        sub = "https://meet.google.com/obu-ev"
                        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver') 
                        Glogin(mail_address, password)
                        time.sleep(60)
                        driver.close()

                elif hour==5:
                        time.sleep((72 - minutes)* 60) #It will sleep until minutes are 12
```